# Como utilizar variáveis em um local fora do escopo onde foram criadas?

Tags: java, android, orientação-a-objetos, encapsulamento

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
public class TracoActivity extends Activity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_traco);

        int mc = 15;

    } //fecha onCreate


    public void ver_log(View v){
       DialogLog(); 
    }

    private void DialogLog(){
        final Dialog dialogLog = new Dialog(this);
        dialogLog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialogLog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_log);

        TextView relatorio = (TextView) dialogLog.findViewById(R.id.relatorio);
        final Button btnFechar = (Button) dialogLog.findViewById(R.id.btn_fechar);

        relatorio.setText("MC = "+mc);

        btnFechar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialogLog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialogLog.show();
    }

} //fecha class TracoActivity
```

Variável `mc` dentro do `onCreate`: "The value of the local variable mc is not used"

Variável `mc` fora do `onCreate`: "mc cannot be resolved to a variable"

Como posso utilizar a variável fora do `onCreate`?

Comment: Use como variável membro da classe.

Comment: depois de `public class TracoActivity extends Activity {` coloque `private int mc;`. Aí você poderá fazer `mc = 15;` no `onCreate`, e acessar no `DialogLog`. Estude OOP em Java.

Comment: @pepper_chico Muito obrigado! Estudarei mais a respeito :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sempre que você precisa de uma variável em determinado escopo você deve declará-la naquele escopo.

Se você declarar em um escopo exterior ao que você precisa ela está acessível mais do que deveria. O compilador não dará erro mas o código permitirá uma utilização equivocada dela. Pode não ocorrer na hora mas no futuro pode esquecer que ela não deveria ser usada e pode até usar uma variável pensando que é outra.

Se declarar em um escopo interior a variável não estar disponível para outra parte do código que você precisa. Neste caso se você declarar `mc` fora do método, ou seja, dentro da classe a variável está disponível para toda a classe, portanto acessível por toda a classe.

Ao contrário da variável do método que é sempre local, ou seja, ninguém pode vê-la a não ser o método, uma variável de classe pode ser visível só dentro da classe ou também fora da classe. Quase sempre deixar uma variável de classe visível diretamente fora dela é considerado uma quebra da abstração que pode ser considerado um princípio da orientação a objeto. É a mesma coisa que você fez com alguns métodos, você disse que eles são privados e não podem ser visíveis fora da classe, ou seja, é um detalhe de implementação, te dá mais liberdade de manutenção. Sempre que possível qualquer membro deveria ser privado, ou seja, o menos visível possível.

Você pode estar se perguntando, se uma variável quase sempre deveria ser privada como acessá-la externamente à classe? Através dos chamados métodos acessadores. Você já viu métodos declarados como `getCampo()` e `setCampo()`? São eles. Obviamente eles precisam ser públicos para dar acesso externo. Em geral eles são criados em pares mas pode ter apenas um deles. Ou pode ter um deles público e o outro privado. Você pode ter códigos complexos dentro dele mas o mais comum é ter apenas `return campo;` e `this.campo = parametro;` respectivamente.

Notou esse `this`? Talvez já saiba usá-lo e ele pode ser opcional em diversos casos mas alguns programadores gostam de usar sempre para garantir não haver ambiguidade, não confundir uma variável de classe com uma variável local ou parâmetro. Pode ser exagero colocar sempre mas se colocar fica mais explícito que a variável é de classe. No fundo o `this` é um parâmetro que todo método recebe sem você ver e nele consta todos os membros da classe.

Seu código ficaria assim:

```
public class TracoActivity extends Activity {
    private int mc;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_traco);
        mc = 15;
    } //fecha onCreate

    public void ver_log(View v){
        DialogLog(); 
    }

    private void DialogLog(){
        final Dialog dialogLog = new Dialog(this);
        dialogLog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialogLog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_log);
        TextView relatorio = (TextView) dialogLog.findViewById(R.id.relatorio);
        final Button btnFechar = (Button) dialogLog.findViewById(R.id.btn_fechar);
        relatorio.setText("MC = " + mc);
        btnFechar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialogLog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialogLog.show();
    }
} //fecha class TracoActivity
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Syntax/VariableScope.java).