# Devolver o foco a um JFormatedTextField depois de clique em botão

Tags: java, swing

Estou precisando que ao clicar no **Botão Limpar** na tela de Login o CPF e Senha o cursor volte para campo do CPF.

```
JFormattedTextField ftUsuario = new JFormattedTextField();
        try {
              MaskFormatter formatter;
              formatter = new MaskFormatter("###.###.###-##");
              formatter.setPlaceholderCharacter('#');
              ftUsuario = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Informe o seu CPF", "Aviso!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }

JButton btnLimpar = new JButton("Limpar");
    btnLimpar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            pfSenha.setText(null);
            ftUsuario.requestFocus(); // AQUI É EXIBIDO O ERRO...
        }
    });
```

Comment: E qual o problema que está enfrentando?

Comment: ftUsuario.requestFocus(); diz: Local Variable ftUsuario defined in an enclosing scope must be final  or effectively final.

Comment: Se for definido com FINAL ele dá erro em outro campo...

Comment: Então mude o escopo do campo para nivel de classe. Se for escopo local(dentro do metodo), para chamar em classe anonima só se for final.

Comment: Se eu for em 'Expose component' e definir public ou protect o erro desaparece porém mesmo clicando em Limpar o cursor não retorna para o campo do CPF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está tentando utilizar uma variável com escopo local(ou seja, criada dentro do método atual), em uma [classe anônima](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/121165/28595), e isso somente é possivel se a variável for declarada como final.

Declare a variável como `final`:

```
final JFormattedTextField ftUsuario = new JFormattedTextField();

//...

btnLimpar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        pfSenha.setText(null);
        ftUsuario.requestFocus(); // AQUI É EXIBIDO O ERRO...
    }
});
```

Ou então mude o escopo do seu botão para nivel da classe, exemplo:

```
public class SuaClasse {

     JFormattedTextField ftUsuario = new JFormattedTextField();

    //...


   private SuaClasse{

       btnLimpar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            pfSenha.setText(null);
            ftUsuario.requestFocus(); 
         }
      });

    //restante do seu código
}
```

Segue algumas referências para leitura sobre escopo de variável:

[Como utilizar variáveis em um local fora do escopo onde foram criadas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45132/como-utilizar-vari%C3%A1veis-em-um-local-fora-do-escopo-onde-foram-criadas)

[Qual a diferença entre escopo e tempo de vida?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/135572/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-escopo-e-tempo-de-vida)

Comment: Excelente, resolvido!